# Changing/removing password in a .qcow2 virtualization

Tags: centos, password, kvm

I downloaded a .qcow2 image from cloud.centos.org, and have been attempting to change the password so I can log into it when loaded into a virtual environment. I tried editing /etc/shadow using virt-edit:

`virt-edit -a CentOS-6-x86_64-GenericCloud-1604.qcow2 /etc/shadow`

I tried first generating a password using `openssl passwd -l` and putting that in there, and when that didn't work I tried copying the encrypted password from another machine, but that also didn't work. I then tried editing /etc/passwd and removing the "x", which from what I understand would allow me to log in with no password:

`root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

But that did not work either. I verified that console and tty through tty11 are in /etc/securetty, and I am not sure where to go from here.

Edit: `virt-customize -a CentOS-6-x86_64-GenericCloud-1603.qcow2 --root-password password:password` did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Was the virtual machine already running when you made your edit?

What does "did not work" mean: did the VM drop to single-user mode, or did it just reject your login?

Note that CentOS most likely has SELinux enabled, so you'll want to do the equivalent of `touch /.autorelabel` for the root filesystem of the VM to trigger SELinux relabeling when the VM boots after your modifications. For example:

```
touch .autorelabel
virt-copy-in -a CentOS-6-x86_64-GenericCloud-1603.qcow2 .autorelabel /
```

Also note that the image includes `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`, which suggests it has been equipped with `cloud-init`, and its configuration (view with `virt-cat -a CentOS-6-x86_64-GenericCloud-1603.qcow2 /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`):

```
users:
 - default

disable_root: 1    <--- this might be the root cause of your troubles!
ssh_pwauth:   0
[...]
```

I tried running `virt-customize --uninstall cloud-init` on the image as suggested elsewhere, but that did not work for me. Perhaps the CentOS 6 is too old to allow package manipulations within the image, at least with the tools I have currently installed?

Anyway, you could probably brute-force disable it by overwriting `/etc/init.d/cloud-config`, `/etc/init.d/cloud-final`, `/etc/init.d/cloud-init` and `/etc/init.d/cloud-init-local` within the VM with a script that just exits, and then once the VM is running and accessible, run `yum erase cloud-init` within the VM?

Comment: The VM was not running when I made my edits. I deleted it from Boxes between each attempt, and it rejected the logins altogether. I also just tried this command with a completely fresh download to no avail:

`virt-customize -a CentOS-6-x86_64-GenericCloud-1603.qcow2 --root-password password:password`

Comment: `touch /.autorelabel` did not make a difference.

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm still a bit confused on which virtualization method you are using, as `Boxes` and the `qcow2` format suggest you are using KVM virtualization, but your question is tagged "virtualbox" which is a specific product from Oracle.

Comment: My bad, fixed the tags. I did enable root and made some other edits using `virt-edit`. Using `virt-customize` on a .qcow of a regular installation of CentOS (ie. not cloud) of the same version, 6.7, works fine. It doesn't look like I am even getting a grub menu with the cloud version.